# search a keyword in file and replace line next to it

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have a file which requires modification via a shell script.

Need to do the following:
1. search for a keyword in the file.
2. replace the next line to this keyword with my supplied line text.

for e.g., my file has the following text:

(some text)
(some text)
(text_to_search)
(text_to_replace)
(some text)
(some text)
(some text)

I need to search the file for  and rewrite the file replace the line  leaving the remaining content untouched.

How can this be done?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk ' zap==1 {print "my new line goes here"; zap=0; next}
      /my pattern/ {zap=1; print $0; next}
      {print $0} '  infile > newfile
```

Assuming I got what you wanted....

```
   var="this is the line of text to insert" 
   awk -v lin="$var"  ' zap==1 {print lin ; zap=0; next}
          /my pattern/ {zap=1; print $0; next}
          {print $0} '  infile > newfile
```

the awk internal variable `lin`, defined: `-v lin="$var"` is named `lin`, `lin` comes from the external bash variable `var`.

Comment: Nothing - it is just a variable like foo or bar.  When set to 1, zap means print the new line you supply not the line from the file in the logic of the awk code.

Comment: one more thing. in this command, i want the "my new line goes here" to be taken as input parameter from command line. I tried using $1, where $1 was the input param to the script. it simply placed the $1 in that line.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -i '/pattern/r/dev/stdin' file
```

the script will wait for us to enter the newline and press ctrl +d interactively +

Answer (score 0):

```
   cat file
```

---

```
first
second
third
fourth
fiveth
```

---

```
set var = "inserted"
sed '/second/a\'$var file
```

---

```
first
second
inserted
third
fourth
fiveth
```